# how to create one to many relational record using nodejs and sequelize-typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize-typescript

I am learning Nodejs with sequelize-typescript my task is to create crud system for one to many relationship. I search a lot but cant find that what is wrong in my code. I successfully get the record using postman but cant create record properly when I post below mention json only the parent record has been set.

```
{
    "mainitemcode": "00013",
    "mainitemcodeDetails": "00013",
    "disabled": false,
    "description": "any discription",
    "finishGoodsRecipeList": [
        {
            "assembling_master_code": "00013",
            "mainitemcode": "00013",
            "subitemcode": "00015",
            "description": "null",
            "qty": 1.000000,
            "wastage_qty": 0.000000
        },
        {
            "assembling_master_code": "00013",
            "mainitemcode": "00011",
            "subitemcode": "00014",
            "description": "null",
            "qty": 1.000000,
            "wastage_qty": 0.000000
        }
    ]
}
```

finishGoodsRecipeListService:

```
  findOne(code: string): Promise<FinishGoodsRecipeMaster> {
    return this.FinishGoodsRecipeMasterModel.findOne({
      include:[FinishGoodsRecipeList,Product],
      where:{mainitemcode:code}
    });
  }

  create(CreatefinishGoodsRecipeListDto: CreatefinishGoodsRecipeListDto): Promise<FinishGoodsRecipeMaster> {
    let t:any= CreatefinishGoodsRecipeListDto
    return this.FinishGoodsRecipeMasterModel.create(t)
  }
```

FinishGoodsRecipeMaster:

```
  @Table({
    tableName: 'assembling_master',
    timestamps: true})
  export class FinishGoodsRecipeMaster extends Model {

    // @PrimaryKey
    @Column({autoIncrement: true})
    idno: number;
    
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    mainitemcode: string;

    @Column
    disabled: number;

    @Column
    description: string;

    @CreatedAt
    @Column({ field: 'created_at' })
    createdAt: Date;

    @UpdatedAt
    @Column({ field: 'updated_at' })
    updatedAt: Date;

    @DeletedAt
    @Column({ field: 'deleted_at' })
    deletedAt: Date;

    @HasOne(() => Product, 'code')
    mainitemcodeDetails:Product;

    @HasMany(() => FinishGoodsRecipeList)
    finishGoodsRecipeList: FinishGoodsRecipeList[];

  }
```

FinishGoodsRecipeList:

```
@Table({
   tableName: 'assembling_list',
   timestamps: true})
export class FinishGoodsRecipeList extends Model {
@PrimaryKey
@Column
idno: number;

@ForeignKey(() => FinishGoodsRecipeMaster)
@Column
mainitemcode: string;

@Column
subitemcode: string;

@Column
description: string;

@Column
qty: number;

@CreatedAt
@Column({ field: 'created_at' })
createdAt: Date;

@UpdatedAt
@Column({ field: 'updated_at' })
updatedAt: Date;

@DeletedAt
@Column({ field: 'deleted_at' })
deletedAt: Date;

@BelongsTo(() => FinishGoodsRecipeMaster) 
FinishGoodsRecipeMaster: FinishGoodsRecipeMaster;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.create()` call also needs an `include` clause.

```
    return this.FinishGoodsRecipeMasterModel.create(t, {
      include: ...
    })
```

Here is the relevant documentation: [Creating With Associations](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/creating-with-associations/)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who still encounter this issue.

I was also stumbling, and did tried with the `include` option, but was unable to get it work.

What I did was this.

When I declare model class `export default class Product extends Model{}`, it does not work.

Then I tried with this `export default class Product extends Model<Product>{}`, then it worked.

The fix: **Adding current Model(i.e, *Product* in this case) to sequelize-typescript's Model generic bracket**